# android parse - getting email ids from parse User class

Tags: java, android, email, parse-platform, parse-server

> I'm trying to get e-mail addresses from parse User class,
>   here I'm trying to get other users email id's when logging in a
>   user, logged in users email id is showing but other users email ids
>   are not showing always null

---

> I try **use master key** also, still not working ,

---

> below is my java code.

```
 String objectId;
    protected TextView txtv;
    protected TextView txtv1;
    protected ImageView txtv2;
    protected ImageView txtv3;
    protected TextView individualOrganization;
    Button emailPerson;
    Button callPerson;
    Button callPersonTelephone;
    ParseObject personObject;
    String personEmail;
    String personNumber;
    String personNumberTelephone;
    ParseQuery query;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_individual);

            txtv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt123);
            txtv1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.coporateSector);
            txtv2 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.txt12345);
            txtv3 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.txt123456);
            individualOrganization =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.individualOrganization);
            Intent i =getIntent();
            objectId = i.getStringExtra("objectId");

            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            //query.put("useMasterKey", true);
            query.setLimit(2000);
            query.include("email");

            query.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {

                @Override
                public void done(final ParseUser object, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {


                        personObject = object;
                        String username = object.getString("firstname");
                        txtv.setText(username + " " + object.getString("lastname"));
                        String position = object.getString("position");
                        txtv1.setText(position);
                        String organizationName = object.getString("organizationName");
                        individualOrganization.setText(organizationName);



                        URL url = null;
                        try {
                            url = new URL("" + object.getString("image"));
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load(String.valueOf(url))
                                .into(txtv2);
                        try {
                            url = new URL("" + object.getString("image"));
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load(String.valueOf(url))
                                .into(txtv3);
    //                    try{
    //                        JSONObject jsonObject = parseObjectToJson(object);
    //                        Log.d("Object", jsonObject.toString());
    //                        Log.d("Email", "+" + object.get("email"));
    //                        personNumber = jsonObject.getString("telephone");
    //                        //personEmail = jsonObject.getString("email");
    //                        personEmail= object.getEmail();
    //
    //                    }catch (JSONException je){
    //                    }catch (ParseException pe){
    //                    } catch (com.parse.ParseException e1) {
    //                        e1.printStackTrace();
    //                    }




                    } else {
                    }

                    callPerson = (Button) findViewById(R.id.individualMobile) ;
                    personNumber = object.getString("mobile");
                    callPerson.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:"+personNumber));
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });
                    if(personNumber==null || personNumber.equals("") || personNumber.equals(" ")){
                        callPerson.setClickable(false);
                        callPerson.setEnabled(false);
                        callPerson.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else{
                        callPerson.setEnabled(true);
                        callPerson.setClickable(true);
                        callPerson.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    callPersonTelephone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.individualTelephone);
                    personNumberTelephone = object.getString("telephone");
                    callPersonTelephone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:"+personNumberTelephone));
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });
                    if(personNumberTelephone==null || personNumberTelephone.equals("")  || personNumberTelephone.equals(" ") || personNumberTelephone.equals("6855")){
                        callPersonTelephone.setClickable(false);
                        callPersonTelephone.setEnabled(false);
                        callPersonTelephone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else{
                        callPersonTelephone.setEnabled(true);
                        callPersonTelephone.setClickable(true);
                        callPersonTelephone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    emailPerson = (Button)findViewById(R.id.individualEmail);
                    object.put("useMasterKey", true);
                    personEmail= object.getString("email");
                    emailPerson.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                            i.setType("plain/text");

                            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {personEmail});
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });
                    if(personEmail==null || personEmail.equals("")  || personEmail.equals(" ")){
                        emailPerson.setClickable(false);
                        emailPerson.setEnabled(false);
                        emailPerson.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else{
                        emailPerson.setEnabled(true);
                        emailPerson.setClickable(true);
                        emailPerson.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    individualOrganization.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String organizationID = personObject.getString("organizationID");
                            if(organizationID == null || organizationID.equals("")){
                                Toast.makeText(SingleIndividual.this, "Sorry No Organization Available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleCorporate.class);
                                i.putExtra("objectId", organizationID);
                                i.putExtra("image", organizationID);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        private JSONObject parseObjectToJson(ParseObject parseObject) throws ParseException, JSONException, com.parse.ParseException {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            parseObject.fetchIfNeeded();
            Set<String> keys = parseObject.keySet();

            for (String key : keys) {
                Object objectValue = parseObject.get(key);
                if (objectValue instanceof ParseObject) {
                    jsonObject.put(key, parseObjectToJson(parseObject.getParseObject(key)));


                } else if (objectValue instanceof ParseRelation) {
                } else {
                    jsonObject.put(key, objectValue.toString());

                }
            }
            return jsonObject;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master Key can only be used from your server code, not client code. Making your users public read is an option, albeit a very poor one. It would be a better idea to have a cloud code function in which you validate a user session, ensure they're able to access this information, and do the query from there, using the master key.

Comment: hi thanks,  @Jake T. one small question,  Is there no way that I can enable master key form my android app , I mean Java code?

Comment: Absolutely none. The point of a master key is that it literally unlocks everything in your code. Why would you want to give that power to a client? Clients can be decompiled, their network activity easily sniffed. Your client key, for example, can be obtained easily. That's why you have a master key in the first place.